# ID2D1RenderTarget::FillOpacityMask render with low resolution

Tags: direct2d, opacitymask

here i got some images i rendered with ID2D1RenderTarget::FillOpacityMask (i actuall call this funtion with a ID2D1DeviceContext2 pointer but it reference to ID2D1RenderTarget interface...).

[image]
[image: cicle]

So i'm not happy of the rendering quality. The original image has perfect resolution and is much bigger than the limit rectangle i render it into.

```
d2d_device_context->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
     wicConverter,
     NULL,
     &bitmap
);

d2d_device_context->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED);
d2d_device_context->FillOpacityMask(
    myBitmap,
    myBrushMask,
    D2D1_OPACITY_MASK_CONTENT_GRAPHICS,
    limitRect,
    renderRect
);
d2d_device_context->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE);
```

This is the code i use. It not take any agument to select `D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE` like `DrawBitmap` or `DrawImage` does.

How can i increase the rendering quality?

Comment: Difficult to determine what's supposed to be the input, the mask and the output from your images. Also the output depends on how you loaded (properties, extend mode, interpolation) the bitmap and the brush in first place, which you don't show any code for. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/opacity-masks-overview and possibly this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-clip-with-bitmap-masks

Comment: @SimonMourier the original image has way better resolution that it even need and is bigger so has even more information. I'm very sure it is the scaling algorirm d2d use for this as i had the same problem with ```DrawBitmap``` when i used nearest neighbour parameter or other parameters that do scalling faster but quality isn't very good...